# Exclude package from Jar

Tags: jersey, maven-3

I am getting an error during Maven build

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map

I am using Jersey 2 but in my project there is one dependency project that is using Jersey 1(and I can't change this project).

And this error is coming because in Jersey 1 and Jersey 2 there is **`javax.ws.rs.core.Application`** class but only difference is in Jersey 1 its without `getProperties()`. So when I am doing a maven build its find the **`javax.ws.rs.core.Application`** class from **`com.sun.jersey`** jar.

Now, I want to exclude the **`javax.ws.rs.core`** package in **`com.sun.jersey`** jar so that when I do build Jersey 2 **`javax.ws.rs.core.Application`** class is is picked.

I have also tried Maven shade but its not working for me.

Please help me on this.

Comment: if your project is being tighly coupled with jersey 1, then why are you using jersey 2 ? any specific reason ?

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thanks for your reply. Yes, actually I want to intercept the request to make some pre-validation and Jesery 2 ContainerRequestFilter has better methods to do that. Thanks,Kamal

Comment: It is obvious that, you can't use both library at same time, other they could have come together rather in different version